# How to check current customer ordered with Purchase Order number in past?

Tags: magento-1.9, purchase-order

How to check current customer ordered with Purchase Order number in past?

If any ordered with "Purchase Order Number" then print that number.

If you have any idea please help.

Comment: can you please specified magneto version?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Get only single order number to current customer:**

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if($customer && $customer->getId()) {
     $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->setCurPage(1);
     if($orders->getSize()) {
         foreach($orders as $order) {
            echo $order->getPayment()->getPoNumber();
            echo "<br>";
         }
     }
}
```

**Get all orders number to current customer:**

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if($customer && $customer->getId()) {
     $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
     if($orders->getSize()) {
         foreach($orders as $order) {
            echo $order->getPayment()->getPoNumber();
            echo "<br>";
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Not getting $order->getPoNumber()  @Abdul

Comment: Try This: echo $order->getPayment()->getPoNumber();